# execute a synapseRT Testcase in GitLab pipeline

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

We have gitlab pipeline for our project. I am facing some gitlab errors

> How can I execute a SynapseRT testcase in GitLab pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Following steps below:

1. Synced Testcase to synapseRT Testsuite.
2. Uploaded Testcase to Gitlab.
3. Created Test Plan and Test Cycle and Add the Testcase to the same.
4. Updated config properties.
5. Updated init properties.
6. Then Executed the pipeline in Gitlab
   Job got successful.